# Can't access jupyterhub in a docker container with netowrk_mode: host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jupyterhub

I have a jupyterhub running in a container with network_mode: host due to some requirement.
However after setting the network_mode to host in my docker-compose file, I can't access jupyterhub from an external host using the host ip:8000.

my understanding from [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) is

> If you use the host network mode for a container, that container’s
>   network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container
>   shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not
>   get its own IP-address allocated. For instance, if you run a container
>   which binds to port 80 and you use host networking, the container’s
>   application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address.

Is there anything i am missing?

EDIT:
To simplify i follow the instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/)

```
docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx
```

I can access the nginx welcome page doing

```
$ curl localhost:80
```

but if i try to curl from another host i get

```
$ curl 10.230.0.123:80
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.230.0.123:80; No route to host
```

Comment: can you verify if firewall is running on your machine and is not blocking the port 80 access?

Comment: yup, the firewall is indeed blocking the port. I am able to access jupyterhub after enabling the port. Thanks for the help @akazuko

Comment: cool, adding that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can happen when on your system firewall is active and is blocking the port access. You can enable port access using below:

```
# in centos7, by updating iptables rules
iptables -I INPUT 5 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# in ubuntu
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
```